# How to use nhanes data to do mediation analysis

Tags: r

I have been trying to use nhanes data to do a mediation analysis. The main model is a logistic regression model.

I tried the mediation package first, but it can't use the weights of the nhanes data. I also tried the lavaan.survey package, but it doesn't fit a logistics regression model. Which R package should I use?